# Storing list of values in SQL row

Tags: java, sql

I have an account model which should have a field  (list of Balances) , I am lost in terms of how to store a list, so far i ended up writing the following:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Table("account")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account {
    @Id
    private Long accountId;

    @Column("customer_id")
    private Long customerId;

    List<Balance> balances;
}
```

Sql file

```
  CREATE TABLE Account
(
    accountId  int,
    customerId  int

);
```

Updated:
Account class

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name ="balance_id")
List<Balance> balances;

public class Balance {

    @Id
    Long balanceId;

    @Column("account_id")
     @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    Account accountId;
```

I am still confused on how to add it to my account table in sql query

```
    CREATE TABLE account
(
    accountId  int,
    customerId  int
  

);

CREATE TABLE balance
(
    balanceId  int,
    accountId  int,
    currency VARCHAR(200),
    amount BIGINT

);
```

Comment: 1-n (one to many) relationship is the term you're looking for. Create a separate table for your balances and store the balances there, reference the account by its account ID.

Comment: @jAC hey man, thank you for your comment, the idea is that account can refer to multiple balance records because balance have different currency and the amount,  so basically what you referring is to add one to many relationship to account List<Balance> balances and in Balance   joincolumn account id ? I have updated my code above